# Generate random numbers based on column length (oracle)

Tags: oracle, random, oracle19c

I have list of numbers start from

```
100000000000000000
```

to

```
100000000000999999
```

always 18 digit.

Now, I want to **generate random numbers** between **100000000000000000** and **100000000000999999**. (need to have 18 digit)

```
declare
 cursor c1 is select * from testNumbers k for update;
 minNumbers INTEGER;
 maxNumbers INTEGER;
 
begin

 select LENGTH(min(someColumn)) into minNumbers from testNumbers; 
 select min(someColumn) into maxNumbers from testNumbers;

  open c1;
    loop fetch c1 into i; 
      exit when c1%notfound;
      
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TRUNC(dbms_random.value (minNumbers, maxNumbers)));

    end loop;
  close c1;
  
end;
```

But I got 16 or 17 digit numbers like:

```
58637356300054590
1502386622593360
34871420042208564
2696370666671141
62734000905097141
```

When I change to:

```
select max(someColumn) into maxNumbers from testNumbers
```

did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to generate random numbers between 100000000000000000 and 100000000000999999

Use the `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` method from the minimum value to the maximum value + 1 and then `FLOOR` the random value:

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(
         DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(
           100000000000000000,
           100000000001000000
         )
       ) AS random_value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which may, randomly, output:

| RANDOM_VALUE |
| --- |
| 100000000000102434 |

If you want to use your minimum and maximum values then use `MIN` and `MAX` (and not `LENGTH`):

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(
         DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(
           MIN(someColumn),
           MAX(someColumn) + 1
         )
       ) AS random_value
FROM   testNumbers;
```

or, if you want to output a random value for every row then use analytic functions (rather than aggregation):

```sql
SELECT someColumn,
       FLOOR(
         DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(
           MIN(someColumn) OVER (),
           MAX(someColumn) OVER () + 1
         )
       ) AS random_value
FROM   testNumbers;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NpzOcT3F)

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is you are taking Length of the MIN Value number instead of actual number for `minNumbers` and in `maxNumbers` number you care using min number.

```
select LENGTH(min(someColumn)) into minNumbers from testNumbers; 
select min(someColumn) into maxNumbers from testNumbers;
```

should be replaced with

```
select min(someColumn) into minNumbers from testNumbers; 
select max(someColumn) into maxNumbers from testNumbers;
```

and also use `TRUNC/FLOOR` with randomly generated number.